Should Philosophy delete majority ChatGPT answers?
I was surprised to see a user copy-and-paste from ChatGPT into this answer. In this case the user did include a couple of sentences of their own before dumping the output of ChatGPT for the rest of the answer.
Is this something that Philosophy SE wants to allow, tolerate, or permit?

Tnx @PhilipKlöcking. Since that question is the more open-to-discussion version, whereas this one pre-decides policy without even checking the current status quo, I think this discussion is better continued there than here.

I agree it should be closed as duplicate, I foolishly searched ChatGPT rather than generative AI and missed it. I do not agree the question pre-decides policy.

@JackAidley Its true the question — literally — does not pre-decide policy. The sole answer you provide definitely does. The normal practice on SE metas when one wants to have a discussion (rather than make a complaint) is to provide more than one competing/contrasting answers which other users can choose or vote or comment on

@Rushi seems to me better to let others with differing views provide those answers.

If you put the above comment into the question body, the tenor and openness of the question significantly changes

@PhilipKlöcking Since the general voting consensus indicates a direction the opposite way than my answer, maybe this question should stay open so that others can express themselves?  [What that vote means is another question... Do people believe they can wish LLMs out of existence?  But I know SE well enough to not bother to ask people to explain their votes]

Philosophy SE should delete answers using Generative AI
In my opinion, all Stack Exchanges should have zero tolerance for generative AI, deleting messages that use it and sanctioning repeat offenders who use such AI. There are several reasons for this:
Stack Exchange is for human expertise
The purpose of a Stack Exchange, any Stack Exchange, is to collect answers from knowledgeable people regarding the questions asked. Using Generative AI undermines this purpose by substituting human intelligence for whatever the LLM has scraped off the net. Maybe the User posting it has the knowledge to assess the answer given, maybe not - we cannot tell.
Generative AI answers have no added value
If someone wants to know what answer an LLM will spit out, they can simply go and ask an AI. Copying and pasting that answer does not add any value to the site, it is no better than simply going to Google and posting the top hit.
LLMs are prone to "hallucination" - i.e. making stuff up
But generative AI answers are even less reliable than taking the top hit and posting that because they are prone to simply making stuff up, whilst also being very good at making those inventions look plausible to non-expert readers.
The legal status of AI answers remains uncertain
There are numerous court cases currently active over whether AI organisations have the right to scrape information off the information to train their models, and it is at time of posting unclear what the outcome of these cases will be. Allowing AI answers risks poisoning the dataset with text of uncertain copyright status.

It's not always that easy to detect gen AI, but certainly "here's what ChatGPT says" should not be acceptable.

The thing that gets me is that LLMs could take the content of Questions and Answers here as input. If they were providing those posts, it would be like trying to  breathe with a bag over your head.

The AI-generated content policy for this site is at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/gen-ai-policy . Rushi did follow the rules of this policy by labeling his content as AI-generated. However, since this content was his entire answer, I'd call that very low effort/low quality. I don't want to be a gatekeeper about what thoughts are allowed here but they should be your thoughts!
I suppose this is somewhat of a judgment call though. The argument could be made that by curating the ChatGPT results and choosing to post them because he agrees with them, he is making them his own thoughts. Like the controversy over whether someone curating prompts to Midjourney to create a desired image can be an "artist." Still, in my opinion, you should at least put it in your own words or add some commentary to make it your own.

Tnx for a reasonable and correct (in the sense of rule abiding) position. "Still, in my opinion, you should at least put it in your own words or add some commentary to make it your own" Haven't I already done so in 2019 which I linked to in this answer?

@Rushi All the information necessary for an answer should be included within that answer. If you repeated the parts of your 2019 post that you thought were relevant, and used that in a relevant way to interpret and explain what ChatGPT said, then maybe that would be a high enough quality answer, but just linking to it isn't enough.

LLMs are a current reality —
Translation and image recognition is already passe. Beyond that there is
Content Creation,
Programmer Assistants,
Customer Support bots
and much else
This is not a choice.
So what are the Choices?
Before I come to that I need to say that I am a strong AI sceptic. Like Yudkowski, Hinton and so on.
That is, I would prefer a world without this... if I had a choice.
But that's like saying I would prefer a world without war.
I would. But it does not make the dozens of wars going on around the world go away.
A staunch pacifist from Hiroshima-1945 does not have her pacifism save herself from radiation.
War or AI — That's not a choice
So what are the Choices?
The most generic case
The choice — much like liquor, sex-work etc prohibition — is whether to legalize in a controlled manner.
Or to promote a bootlegging mafia
The SE wide choice
The choice of SE for LLM content has been debated. There is a set of decisions and policies — Causative, Phil's links. But it is still strongly questioned — this question and its supporters!
Phil SE
There have been suggestions by experienced users to do their research by — among other things — using LLMs.
This Answer
SE claims its goal is to be a repository of knowledge.
It seems a bit disingenuous that the same site — phil-SE, same subject — Occam, same author — myself is not allowed to connect a current answer with a link to their own earlier non-LLM answer.
tl;dr
LLM's are as much here as search engines were 2 decades ago.
If the suggestion of this question flies all that will happen is that people will not acknowledge their LLM-usage and will cover their tracks.
By making an answer like this (for which I already have a non LLM older similar one) I was exploring the waters whether it is possible to have a more civil, more open and honest forum where people who use it acknowledge this straightforwardly.
Or else we game each in hiding and detecting LLM usage.
For reference:
Just spend a little time searching this meta itself seeing how many people have already started complaining about some user using an LLM — without acknowledging it of course

It reminds me of the debate on whether the Olympics should allow professional athletes. Not allowing just caused a lot of subterfuge. But, drugs / 'doping' is still off-limits, we just have to decide what and then detect it... "Why can't we all just get along?"
